# MySQL - group by non aggregate column alternatives efficiency

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get my head around the most effective way to achieve intended result.
After some reading i realize turning `only_full_group_by=off` is a bad idea.

I have the following data:

**Table test**

> | id | task | user |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 21 | 4 |
> | 2 | 22 | 4 |
> | 3 | 23 | 3 |
> | 4 | 25 | 3 |
> | 5 | 25 | 4 |
> | 6 | 22 | 4 |

**Goal**

i want to return all task values that do not have an other user assigned to it. So `user=4`should return `[21,22]` and `user=3` => `[23]`

**Tried solutions**

to achieve this using `only_full_group_by=off` i put together the following SQL

```
SELECT task, count(distinct user), user  FROM test
GROUP BY task
HAVING count(distinct user) = 1 AND user=4
```

[SQL fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269e01/43/0)

But to achieve a similar result with `only_full_group_by=on` the query seems unnecessarily complex (maybe it isnt, let me know)

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.task, test.user FROM test, (
  SELECT task, count(distinct user)  from test
  GROUP BY task
  HAVING count(distinct user) = 1
) as tmp WHERE user = 4 AND test.task=tmp.task
```

[SQL fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269e01/42/0)

Both queries returns "same" output but the latter seems unnecessarily complex and possibly inefficient. But im no SQL expert.

Is there a more efficient way to achive this outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a `LEFT JOIN` that looks for another user on the same task, then enforce the constraint that this should not match any rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.task, test.user
FROM test
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON
    test.task = t2.task
    AND test.user <> t2.user
WHERE test.user = 4
AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick! Just struggeling to understand why the  ```AND t2.id IS NULL;```is needed?

Comment: nevermind i think realised it. LEFT join populates t2 with null when the conditions in the ```ON``` statement  is not met, hence ```t2.id IS NULL```, cause we dont want t2 to match. ```t2.id``` could have been any field in ```t2``` right?

Comment: Yes, although I would suggest going for the primary key as there can never be a null value in this case.  (I guessed that's what `id` was)

Comment: Good point, I see no reason to not use the primary key (id), just trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This query is essentially the same as [Rob Eyre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437199/mysql-group-by-non-aggregate-column-alternatives-efficiency#77437279) but written using NOT EXISTS, instead of the traditional anti-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.task, t1.user
FROM test t1
WHERE user = 4
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM test t2
    WHERE t1.task = t2.task AND t1.user <> t2.user
);
```

Unless there is a reason for having the surrogate PK, I would remove it and make `(task user)` the PK and add a secondary on `(user, task)`, after removing the duplicates.

```
DELETE t1
FROM test t1
JOIN (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY task, user ORDER BY id) rn FROM test
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.rn > 1;

ALTER TABLE test
  DROP COLUMN id,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (task, user),
  ADD INDEX (user, task);
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G80j3KFT).